# how to split this complex json array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like

```
 ["1-India","2-xxx","3-yyyy"]
```

I want array like

```
["India","xxxx"]
```

Please help me to get this functionality.

Comment: What's complex about that `array`? Because that's not `JSON`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use combination of [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

```js
var newArr = ["1-India","2-xxx","3-yyyy"].map(x=> x.split('-')[1]);
console.log(newArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment. That what you have there, is not an `JSON`, it's an `array`. I think this could be an easy way to achieve what you want:

```js
var arr = ["1-India", "2-xxx", "3-yyyy"];
var newArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  arr[i] = arr[i].replace(/[0-9-]/g, '');
  newArray.push(arr[i]);
}

console.log(newArray)
```